# How to find multiple values in column

Tags: excel

I have problem with matching in excel file. Let me explain it on an example:

```
COL1 COL2    COL3 COL4 COL5 
AA11 First   AA11 ???? ???
BB22 First   BB22 
AA11 Second
BB22 Third
```

1. COL1 - User's indexes
2. Col2 - User's groupName
3. Col3 DISTINCT user's indexes
4. Col4,5... Values that i'm looking for

I'm looking for formulas for following cases:

Column 4: IF user with index COL3 has groups(COL2) 'FIRST' AND 'SECOND' add value = 'LEVEL1'

Column 5: IF user with index COL3 has groups(COL2) 'FIRST' AND 'THIRD add value = 'LEVEL2'

Comment: Have you tried `VLookup`?

Comment: No i did not, i will check it.

Comment: What do you mean by `add`? I am just asking because it seems as if you are trying to add a certain value to another cell. Yet, any Excel formula can only - as a result of its calculation - show a certain value. Yet, it cannot change a value nor can it change the value in another cell.

Comment: EDIT: Smit - i think it won't help me, because VLookup can return only return value that i don't need. I want to find multiple values and if they match some conditions return specific value.

Comment: Ralph add - write, put, whatever - just write a specific value in blanc cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use COUNTIFS wrapped in an IF:

Column 4:

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,C1,B:B,{"First","Second"}))>=2,"Level 1","")
```

Column 5:

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,C1,B:B,{"First","Third"}))>=2,"Level 2","")
```

[image]

Comment: I will check it, but i think it is the answer for my question. Thanks Scott!

Comment: @hakobot just remember to come back and mark as correct if it works.

Comment: Scott Carner - i just checked - it does work! Thank you one more time!